# High frequency model of transistor AC ground AC input

Tags: transistors, capacitor, high-frequency

When creating the high frequency model for transistor circuits, certain capacitances arise. A lot of them are often in parallel to one another(so they add up) or grounded on both sides(so they get erased). If a capacitance has its one end to Vin (AC input) and the other on a random node, should I consider Vin as AC-GROUND, and merge it with other capacitors that go from the random node to AC-GROUND? I saw Behzad Razavi doing it in an online course but I cant't find sources to back it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Vin may have a source impedance internally but an ideal voltage source is 0 ohms so it is an AC ground.